# Exclude items during deserialization if a specific attribute doesn't exist

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON string which can contain multiple students and teachers.  An example is shown below.  I want to deserialize the JSON into separate lists based on whether it contains a particular attribute.

```
[
  {
    "School": "St.Xavier"
  },
  {
    "teacherid": 1,
    "name": "Prof.Xavier",
    "position": "Professor",
    "class": "elite"
  },
  {
    "studentid": 1,
    "name": "QuickSilver",
    "ability": "Rush",
    "class": "elite"
  }
]
```

For example:

```
List<Teacher> teacherList = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Teacher>(json);
List<Student> studentList = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Student>(json);
```

During deserialization, school info will be ignored, and each list will contain only those items with attributes matching according to the class. So `teacherList` will contain only teacher info, and `studentList` will contain only student info.

```
public class Teacher
{
    [JsonProperty("teacherid")]
    public string TeacherID {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("position")]
    public string Position {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("class")]
    public string InCharge {get;set;}
}

public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("studentid")]
    public string StudentID {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("ability")]
    public string Ability {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("class")]
    public string Enrolled {get;set;}
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple helper method to do what you want:

```
public static List<T> Deserialize<T>(string json, string attribute)
{
    return JArray.Parse(json)
                 .Children<JObject>()
                 .Where(jo => jo[attribute] != null)
                 .Select(jo => jo.ToObject<T>())
                 .ToList();
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
List<Teacher> teachers = Deserialize<Teacher>(json, "teacherid");
List<Student> students = Deserialize<Student>(json, "studentid");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/aXQ99x